# No rule to make target 'vexpress_gem5_dvfs_defconfigmake'. Stop

Tags: gem5

I am trying to run DVFS on gem5 that I am trying to create a Makefile Based on this site :http://www.gem5.org/Running_gem5#Experimenting_with_DVFS

When I try to make I get the following error message:

(/home/farideh/linux-linaro-tracking-gem5/scripts/kconfig/Makefile:36: recipe for target 'silentoldconfig' failed
make[2]: *** [silentoldconfig] Error 1
/home/farideh/linux-linaro-tracking-gem5/Makefile:526: recipe for target 'silentoldconfig' failed
make[1]: *** [silentoldconfig] Error 2
make: *** No rule to make target 'vexpress_gem5_dvfs_defconfigmake'.  Stop.)

I don't know this error for things and what do I do by this error?

Comment: Hi, I have never used DVFS, but here are a few thoughts: 1) familiarize yourself with Markdown formatting, e.g. how to use code blocks 2) It is weird that the error says: `vexpress_gem5_dvfs_defconfigmake` and not `vexpress_gem5_dvfs_defconfig`, maybe parallel build? It would be much better to have just `vexpress_gem5_dvfs_defconfig` otherwise Googlers won't find this thread in the future 3) The wiki is highly old and outdated. The fact that it still uses Mercurial to clone is a dead giveaway, so I would not trust it. I would first confirm that DVFS has really not been merged upstream.

Comment: Also, have you grepped the kernel source for that target name? You are likely just on the wrong version of something like that.